# Evaluate object expressions without using eval

Tags: javascript, expression, eval, javascript-objects

How can i evaluate js object expression without using eval. For examples

```
'd3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m))'

'd3.range(n).map(function() {//body})'
```

i want to get the output like

```
var a = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m));
```

Comment: Can you give some more background? Why are you getting these `d3` expressions as strings? Why don't you want to use `eval()` on them? Patrick's answer has some good tips on other ways to evaluate a string expression, but they really boil down to the same thing as `eval()`. So what is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: i want to dynamically construct different charts. so all the d3 expressions as strings are fetched from server as json and i want to evaluate them on the client side. I just want to avoid using eval due to its malicious nature and slow compile time. But i dont know, would it be safe using eval in this particual sceneraio?

Comment: Cool. So you pretty much are going to be using `eval()` in one form or another. Patrick shared a couple of other techniques that you could use, but in essence they do the same thing as `eval()` - take a string and execute it as JavaScript code. (The `Function` approach puts the string inside a function body, so that is one difference.) What are your concerns with using `eval()` for this? Knowing what possible issue with `eval()` you are worried about could inform the search for alternatives.

Comment: i am just fetching expression as json from server side and want to evaluate it to construct the code in the client side. so would eval be safe in this scenerio?

Comment: Who creates those `d3` expressions that you have on the server? Is it your server and you create these expressions, or do they come from user input? If you create them, there's nothing wrong with `eval()`. After all, you trust yourself to run your own JavaScript code, right? If these expressions come from your site visitors, of course it is a very different story!

Comment: All the expressions are created by ourselves or at least we check the expressions if it has to come from others. So, what you are saying is that it is not harmful to use eval if the expression from the server is safe. Thanks very much for point to the right direction.

Comment: In that case, then yes, `eval()` or either of the two similar approaches that Patrick mentioned are fine. Look at it this way: suppose the `d3` expression was not a string, but was simply another line of code in your existing JavaScript code that you've written. That would be OK, of course, yes? Having the expression in a string that you `eval()` is not much different from that.

Comment: One other point to keep in mind: a function that uses `eval()` is hard for JavaScript engines to optimize. So you wouldn't put the `eval()` call in a function that also does a lot of heavy computing. But the `d3` expressions you mentioned shouldn't be a problem at all. You will probably have a simple function of a few lines that does the `eval()` and not much else, right? That _specific_ function won't optimize well, but no worries: the underlying `d3` code that does all the heavy work won't be impacted by that, because it's not in the same function.

Comment: I can have whole expression to construct the chart. for example, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887, i will have to evaluate whole script in index.html (except the d3 source), i hope it will not cause optimization issues

Comment: Aha. Yes, in that case you may well have concerns about the performance of code that is run with `eval()`. As you can see, the `cluster()` and `collide()` functions in that script are fairly compute-intensive. Here's an idea: why don't you study how those `bl.ocks.org` pages are implemented and maybe do something similar?

Comment: Hey finally i figured out the alternative approach which i think will be the best. Constructing Script in the server side and referencing it through script tag at the client. It would eliminate the need to recompile the script. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: That sounds good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `<script>` element and set the string as the `textContent` and then append the script element to the document

```js
var command = 'console.log("test")';
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.textContent = command;
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

You could also pass the string to [`Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), which would create a function with that string as the function's body and then execute the returned function.

```js
var body = 'console.log("test")';
var testFn = Function(body);
testFn();
```

In your particular case you would have to prepend the `var a =` to the string if it wasn't already there. And if you use the `Function()` way you would have to also use the variable in that function as `var` will make it scoped to that function alone.

Comment: Those are both good techniques to know about, but is either one really any different from `eval()`? They may avoid the dreaded letters `e`, `v`, `a`, and `l`, but don't they do pretty much the same thing? If there are differences that may make either one a better choice than `eval()` in certain situations, it would be good to give some detail about that. (Basically, we don't know _why_ the OP wants to avoid `eval()`.)

Comment: My use case is that the evaluated expression returns an object which i later want to use in the script. for example , var a = 'd3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m))'; and later i will like to use a.somemethod()